# Trouble with matrix multiplication in Julia

Tags: julia, matrix-multiplication, jupyter-lab

I'm having trouble with getting the same answer for the same matrix product in Julia.

I'm using Jupyter Lab and have written the following code:

```
using LinearAlgebra

function U1(α, M)
    return exp(α * M)
end

function U2(β, M)
    return exp(β * M)
end

test_list=[1 2]

α_list = test_list[1]
β_list = test_list[2]

M1=[1 3 3; 3 2 2; 2 2 1]
M2=[3 2 1; 3 0 3; 2 1 1]

init_vec=[1 ; 1 ; 1]

for _ in 1:2
    α=α_list[1]
    β=β_list[1]
    final_vec = U1(α,M1) * U2(β,M2) * init_vec
    println(final_vec)
end

#[3.2498540882389616e7, 3.362948386386128e7, 2.2549887512082998e7]
#[3.3668507705110244e7, 3.4777346320714206e7, 2.548964322110533e7]
```

I randomly set the values of `test_list`, `init_vec`, `M1`, and `M2`. As shown, I'm getting random-looking answers.

What could be causing this? How should I modify the code?

Comment: how did you install julia?

Comment: I installed Julia from Anaconda using 'conda install -c conda-forge julia'.

Comment: Version of julia is 1.8.5

Comment: You might want to try the official binaries. Not sure that's the problem, but a lot of linux distros package horribly broken versions of Julia (and conda might be doing so as well).

Answer (score 1):

Running your code in the REPL I get:

```
[3.3668507705110244e7, 3.4777346320714206e7, 2.548964322110533e7]
[3.3668507705110244e7, 3.4777346320714206e7, 2.548964322110533e7]
```

When I replace `test_list`, `M1`, `M2`, and `init_vec` with appropriately sized random inputs I get:

```
[1.6282115006640232, 0.9234175545808518, 3.517098945783593]
[1.6282115006640232, 0.9234175545808518, 3.517098945783593]
```

In other words, I can't reproduce the behaviour you are observing. Have you tried to run the exact code you posted in a fresh Julia session?

---

Edited to add: Based on the comments I also ran your code in an IJulia Jupyter notebook and am getting:

[image]

Note that `using LinearAlgebra` is not required here, you are not actually using any functions that aren't in Base.

As Oscar says, it's not a good idea to install Julia from sources other than the official binaries, so maybe try that.

Comment: When I ran the code in the REPL, as you confirmed, I got the same correct answer both times. However, when I ran the same code in Jupyter Lab or Jupyter Notebook right after restarting the kernel, I got two different answers. Does this seem more like an issue with Jupyter Lab than with Julia itself?

Comment: maybe print values of alpha, beta, M1, M2, and everything else involved in calculation at each iteration so see what exacltly is changing

Comment: I checked that the values of α, β, M1, and M2 were the same both times. However, I changed the code like
`u1= U1(α,M1) 
u2= U2(β,M2)
println("U1=$u1", "\n","U2=$u2")
final_vec = u1 * u2 * init_vec` , then the code returned the answer that U1 and U2 are different in the two trials.

Comment: See my edit above - this also works as expected in a Jupyter notebook